# In Adobe Edge Animate, adding html video in both MP4 and Ogg

Tags: html, video, adobe-edge

I've used a tutorial for Edge Animate to embed an MP4 video into my HTML5 project, but I need to add fallback code to support the .ogg format for firefox.

In edge, the variable vid.html pulls in the HTML..

```
var vid = sym.$("Rectangle");
vid.html('<video width= "300" height= "170" src="powerspin_loop.mp4"   
poster="images/poster" type= "video/mp4" autoplay loop </video>')
```

I'm confused as the video tag is not closed, this above code works fine, but when I add another video tag for .ogg it breaks. Any ideas? I just need to add fallback code for .ogg

The Tutorial I did is Here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGyOxwEsEFo

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
var vid = sym.$("Rectangle");
vid.html('<video width="500" height="300" poster="poster.png" controls>\
<source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> \
<source src="yourVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> \
</video>');
```

remember to use a backslash at each line end.

best regards.